# Simplify Regular Expression with variable amount of alphanumeric character separated by a dash

Tags: regex

I would like to validate a specific string to be correct. A correct string looks like the following:

ab1-peter-application

The rules for the string are `<1-4 alphanumeric characters>-<1-30 alphanumeric characters>-<1-30 alphanumeric characters>`

I just build the regex as following which I guess would work:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}
```

As every segment seems to be the same and the occurrence of the alphanumeric characters vary I feel like it can be shortened. Is there any chance to shorten/simplify this regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the final two parts:

```
-<1-30 alphanumeric characters>-<1-30 alphanumeric characters>
```

into a single group, repeated twice. Additionally, a single character in a character set is superfluous - you can remove the character set entirely, in that case, to make the regex more concise. The same is true for `{1}` (meaningless quantifier):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}){2}
```

Additionally, if possible in your environment, use the case-insensitive flag (so you don't have to repeat `a-zA-Z`) and also use `\d` to represent digits instead of `0-9`:

```
[a-z\d]{1,4}(?:-[a-z\d]{1,30}){2}
```

Answer (score -1):

[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{30}){2}$ - simple Regex to match **exact** length required string.

^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}){2}$  - simple Regex to match **variable** length required

Hope this will help

Comment: lol.. Thats what I had mentioned in my post that it is to match exact string. To match variable string user can easily add the minimum limit to RegEx